# Wifi very slow on Ubuntu 12.04 but not on Win7, need help

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet-connection

I have an enormous problem: I've a Sony Vaio VGN-NR21S with win7 and Ubuntu 12.04 in dual boot. With Windows everything is fine (except that is windows) but with Ubuntu the wireless connection is awfully slow, basically unusable.

I've already search for similar discussion but the solution proposed didn't worked.
I've noticed this issue also in live mode both with ubuntu and linux mint.
I've installed Ubuntu onto an Acer that shows the same problem when connected via wifi to my router, so I think that maybe the issue is about compatibility with my home router.

I really need help, I don't want unistall ubuntu!
Please tell me which output u need to help me, thanks.

Comment: What type of wireless card do you have? (to find out look at the output of `lshw`)

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, here's the output:

Comment: `           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 61
                serial: 00:1d:e0:58:cf:b3
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless`

Comment: configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl4965 driverversion=3.2.0-29-generic-pae firmware=228.61.2.24 ip=192.168.2.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:46 memory:fa000000-fa001fff

Answer (score 1):

I have finally fixed the problem just by disabling the "802.11 n" protocol in the router settings